# Why parent linearLayout consumes all clicks of children?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, bottom-sheet

In my Activity I use *bottom sheet* layout - that is NestedScrollView with id *bottom_sheet*.

Inside that NestedScrollView I have LinearLayout which includes another layout (layout_player).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cl_root"
    >

       <some layouts here />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >

      <include layout="@layout/layout_player"
      />

    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The included `layout_player`layout consist of ConstraintLayout with some Guidelines and RelativeLayout with ImageView inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
>
 ...
<RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rl_play"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineTop"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineBottom"
      app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
  >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

After I set clickListeners for views in layout **layout_player** - the parent LinearLayout with id **player_container** consumes all click of its children. But I need click event on child - not on parent.

**How to enable click on child inside its parent?**

In my case, how to get click event of **RelativeLayout** located inside **ContraintLayout** that is located inside **LinearLayout**?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `descendantFocusability`

On the layout you don't want focus, you can do:

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

This means it will focus on children views before the layout gets the focus.

**EDIT (with example):**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/player_container"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_player" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in `layout_player` file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

 ...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_play"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineTop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineBottom"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So we are adding `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants` line on two different layouts and allowing clicks and focus on `RelativeLayout` by doing this:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Note: If this doesn't work, can you show how you are setting the listeners on the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not help me. It seams like ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView is not working properly.

Comment: Try the example above and if that doesn't work, please show your code on how you set the listeners on `RelativeLayout` and others

Comment: Hi @THEPATEL. Thank you for your reply. Still not works. This is my class where I find the view and set the click listener https://codeshare.io/aJWWVX

Comment: @THEPATEL Also here you can see my Activity layout https://codeshare.io/albbrj and layout layout_player_mini.xml https://codeshare.io/GAmmR8